# R.stamp Segmentation fault when compile android master source

Tags: android, build, makefile, android-source

I have some problem when compile android source code on my old laptop DELL Latitude D620(Intel T5500 with Ubuntu 11.10)

Here is the error code:

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=AOSP
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.0.9.99.999.9999.99999
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.0.0-23-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-11.10-oneiric
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=OPENMASTER
OUT_DIR=out
============================================

...
compile progress..
...

host Java: draw9patch (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/draw9patch_intermediates/classes)
host Java: hierarchyviewer (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/hierarchyviewer_intermediates/classes)
Note: sdk/draw9patch/src/com/android/draw9patch/ui/ImageTransferHandler.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/layoutlib_api.jar
Install: out/host/linux-x86/framework/layoutlib_create.jar
host Java: lint_api (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/lint_api_intermediates/classes)
host Java: signature-tools (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/signature-tools_intermediates/classes)
host Java: traceview (out/host/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/traceview_intermediates/classes)
target R.java/Manifest.java: ApplicationsProvider (out/target/common/obj/APPS/ApplicationsProvider_intermediates/src/R.stamp)
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/APPS/ApplicationsProvider_intermediates/src/R.stamp] Segmentation fault
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

If I 'make clean' and compile the code again, it may error in the other module like 'CalendarProvider_intermediates' and so on.

I didn't find similar problem on the Internet, is this a hardware problem?

Comment: Try to download and compile stable branch, not master (sometimes master can have problems).

Comment: One of my friend tried this code and he compiled success. I was always get problem like this or a 'bad CRC' problem. Yet I had finish compile once, but there is no 'emulator' under out/host/linux-x86/bin...

Comment: bad CRC means that the sources were not downloaded correctly (some errors in files). This can be a possible reason why the sources were not compiled.

Comment: Thanks.I tried 2.3.7_r1 and compiled success. But I'm still can't understand this R.stamp error yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and i solved it finally.

My experience is check the website http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

My machine is Ubuntu 14.04, after installing the libs I followed the suggestion. Hope it can help you.

```
sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison gperf build-essential \
  zip curl zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 \
  lib32ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32z-dev ccache \
  libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc unzip
```